# Cost to transpose a directed graph?

Tags: performance, algorithm, graph, computer-science

I am trying to construct the transpose of a directed graph by running DFS on the original graph and then generating a adjancy list of the mirror as new nodes are discovered.

What would the computational time of this be? I know that the DFS takes O(|V| + |E|) but what about constructing the adjancy list? How long does it take to construct the adjancy list of the transpose through DFS?

Comment: is "mirror" a standard term?  google is showing this q as the first hit.  it does not appear in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_graph_theory - do you mean http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose_graph

Comment: @Yes , a transpose graph would be the correct term.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have O(1) insertions of items into your graph (supposing you are using a hashtable or hashmap for vertex lookup or an array if your vertices are represented by integers), then the asymptotic runtime should be no different than the DFS.

I don't think you actually need to do a DFS, to be honest. I think you could just iterate over each vertex's adjacency list and then add the edges that way. The runtime will still be O(V+E), so theoretically, it doesn't really matter.

Also, if your graph is represented as an edge list, then I believe making the transpose graph would just be O(E), but I guess that requires the graph to be connected.

Sorry if there was too much extra information in there, and I hope I was able to help!